# How to display customer's email with the customer ID in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product

I made a product attribute named "Seller ID" which I would give a sample value of "2". How can I display a customer's email and name which has a customer id of "2" or whatever numerical value is in Seller ID attribute?

I'm pretty new to Magento 2 and it would help if you can explain a little.

Thank you!

Comment: You should use the customer data provider and knockout js. A good example to follow is the way that the customer links at the top of the page are rendered. If you use php as the answers below state, your information for one customer will be cached and it will display for the other customers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code.

```
$customerID = 2;
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Customer')
->load($customerID);
$customerEmail = $customerObj->getEmail();
$fname = $customerObj->getFirstName();
```

However it is not recommended to use object manager directly. It's always a better practice to use service contracts.

So you can use `\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface` :

```
protected $_customerRepositoryInterface;
public function __construct(
    ....
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
}
```

Then in your code you can call:

```
$customerId = 2;
$customer = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
$email = $customer->getEmail();
$fname = $customer->getFirstName();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Sample File Path:
>   app/code/YourCompanyName/YourModuleName/Block/YourCustomBlock.php

```
<?php
namespace YourCompanyName\YourModuleName\Block;

class YourCustomBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    protected $_customerFactory;

    protected $_addressFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->_addressFactory = $addressFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getCustomerById($id) {
        return $this->_customerFactory->create()->load($id);
    }

}
```

Now, we can use the functions in our view (.phtml) file as follows.

```
// get customer by id
$customer = $block->getCustomerById(5);

echo $customer->getFirstname() . '<br>';
echo $customer->getLastname() . '<br>';
echo $customer->getEmail() . '<br>';
```

You can get more information from Here : [How to Get Customer Information By Id in Magento 2](http://www.blogtreat.com/how-to-get-customer-information-by-id-in-magento-2/)